# For the same column value counting the number of other column value, and repeating this for all the column values of the python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, data-analysis

[image]

The Image I have shared is my input data or the data from which I have to extract something. Please go through the image to get a better understanding.

How can I calculate the count of another column by fixing my particular column values, and doing such thing for all column values of the dataframe.

INPUT DATAFRAME:

```
+----+--------------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
|    |      A       |    B    |        C        |       D        |
+----+--------------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
|  1 | Sign up date | EP Code | uninstalled_app | total_orders   |
|  2 | 2020-04-01   | 345661  | False           |              0 |
|  3 | 2020-04-04   | 634148  | False           |              0 |
|  4 | 2020-04-04   | 659212  | False           |              6 |
|  5 | 2020-04-04   | 709930  | False           |              1 |
|  6 | 2020-04-04   | 201212  | False           |              0 |
|  7 | 2020-04-04   | 312605  | False           |              0 |
|  8 | 2020-04-04   | 446236  | False           |              2 |
|  9 | 2020-04-04   | 391070  | True            |              7 |
| 10 | 2020-04-04   | 847688  | True            |              1 |
| 11 | 2020-04-04   | 191092  | False           |              0 |
| 12 | 2020-04-04   | 178254  | False           |              0 |
| 13 | 2020-04-04   | 755144  | True            |              1 |
| 14 | 2020-04-13   | 307366  | False           |              2 |
| 15 | 2020-04-13   | 115383  | False           |              3 |
| 16 | 2020-04-13   | 539592  | False           |              0 |
| 17 | 2020-04-13   | 750822  | False           |              4 |
| 18 | 2020-04-13   | 250928  | False           |              1 |
| 19 | 2020-04-13   | 637094  | True            |              0 |
| 20 | 2020-04-13   | 302811  | False           |              0 |
| 21 | 2020-04-13   | 341899  | False           |              0 |
+----+--------------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
```

output DATAFRAME::

```
+---+--------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+
| 1 | Sign up date | no_stores | no_unin_app     no_stores_recei  | ed_order  |
+---+--------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+
| 2 | 2020-04-01   |      1    |             0                    |   0       |
| 3 | 2020-04-04   |     11    |             3                    |   6       |
| 4 | 2020-04-13   |      8    |             1                    |   4       |
+---+--------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: something similar to `df.groupby("Sign up date").count()`

Comment: previous  comment can gives values in first column but I don't understand what means values in next columns - how did you calculate them?

Comment: the 3rd column in the output gives the count of total "True"  for the un-installed app on the same date, and the 4th column in the output gives the count of total non-Zero values in "total_orders" column of the input on the same date. Please ask if there is still some confusion.

Comment: for 3th column I get result `0,3,1`, not `0,6,4` - especially there are only four `True` in all column.

Comment: now I checked 4th column - I get `0,6,4` instead of ` 0,3,1` - it seems you put results in wrong order in question. And it makes only problems when people want to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, and really very sorry for the wrong order of the column values.

Comment: Your code helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first column you can use `groupby('Sign up date')` and then you can calculate values for other columns.

BTW: because `True` is treated as `1` and `False` as `0` so `sum([True, True, False])` gives `2` - and I will use this to count `True` in different moments.

```
 groups = df.groupby('Sign up date')

 groups['Sign up date'].count()
 #groups['Sign up date']apply(lambda x: len(x))

 groups['uninstalled_app'].apply(lambda x: sum(x == True))

 groups['total_orders'].apply(lambda x: sum(x > 0))
```

---

Full example.

BTW: I use `io.StringIO` only to simulate file in memory but you use real file.

```
text ='''Sign up date | EP Code | uninstalled_app | total_orders
2020-04-01   | 345661  | False           |              0

2020-04-04   | 634148  | False           |              0
2020-04-04   | 659212  | False           |              6
2020-04-04   | 709930  | False           |              1
2020-04-04   | 201212  | False           |              0
2020-04-04   | 312605  | False           |              0
2020-04-04   | 446236  | False           |              2
2020-04-04   | 391070  | True            |              7
2020-04-04   | 847688  | True            |              1
2020-04-04   | 191092  | False           |              0
2020-04-04   | 178254  | False           |              0
2020-04-04   | 755144  | True            |              1

2020-04-13   | 307366  | False           |              2
2020-04-13   | 115383  | False           |              3
2020-04-13   | 539592  | False           |              0
2020-04-13   | 750822  | False           |              4
2020-04-13   | 250928  | False           |              1
2020-04-13   | 637094  | True            |              0
2020-04-13   | 302811  | False           |              0
2020-04-13   | 341899  | False           |              0'''

import pandas as pd
import io

#df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+\|\s+', engine='python', header=0)

#print(df)
#print(df.columns)
groups = df.groupby('Sign up date')

print('\n--- Sign up date ---\n')
print(groups['Sign up date'].count())
print('\n--- uninstalled_app ---\n')
print(groups['uninstalled_app'].apply(lambda x: sum(x == True)))
print('\n--- total_orders ---\n')
print(groups['total_orders'].apply(lambda x: sum(x > 0)))
```

Result

```
--- Sign up date ---

Sign up date
2020-04-01     1
2020-04-04    11
2020-04-13     8
Name: Sign up date, dtype: int64

--- uninstalled_app ---

Sign up date
2020-04-01    0
2020-04-04    3
2020-04-13    1
Name: uninstalled_app, dtype: int64

--- total_orders ---

Sign up date
2020-04-01    0
2020-04-04    6
2020-04-13    4
Name: total_orders, dtype: int64
```

---

You can also write it in together

```
result = groups.agg({
    #'Sign up date': 'count', # `count` as string to access internal function in `groupby`
    'Sign up date':    lambda x: len(x),
    'uninstalled_app': lambda x: sum(x == True), 
    'total_orders':    lambda x: sum(x > 0),
})                      

# rename columns
result.columns = ['no_stores', 'no_unin_app', 'no_stores_received_order']

# move `Sign up date` from index to column
result = result.reset_index()

print(result)
```

Result:

```
  Sign up date  no_stores  no_unin_app  no_stores_received_order
0   2020-04-01          1            0                         0
1   2020-04-04         11            3                         6
2   2020-04-13          8            1                         4
```

---

Doc: [groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [more](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html), [Aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation)

---

**EDIT:** In documentation I found `NamedAgg`

```
result = groups.agg(
    no_stores=pd.NamedAgg(column='Sign up date', aggfunc=lambda x: len(x)),
    no_unin_app=pd.NamedAgg(column='uninstalled_app', aggfunc=lambda x: sum(x == True)),
    no_stores_received_order=pd.NamedAgg(column='total_orders', aggfunc=lambda x: sum(x > 0)),
).reset_index()

print(result)
```